# Is it true that if $a>b$ where $a,b\in[0,\infty)$ then $a^x>b^x$ or $a^x<b^x$ for any $x\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ according as $x>0$ or $x<0?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I know the result that **if $a>b$ where $a,b\in[0,\infty)$ then $a^x>b^x$ or $a^x<b^x$ for any $x\in\mathbb Q-\{0\}$ according as $x>0$ or $x<0.$** Does the same hold for irrational number? *i.e.*

> **Is it true** that if $a>b$ where $a,b\in[0,\infty)$ then $a^x>b^x$ or $a^x<b^x$ for any $x\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ according as $x>0$ or $x<0?$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a>0$ and consider $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}(a^x) = xa^{x-1}$. $a^{x-1}>0$, thus $a^x$ increases strictly in $a$ if $x>0$ and decreases strictly if $x<0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is still true.

$a^x$ is defined as $e^{x\ln a}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a>b$, $\ln a>\ln b$ and hence $x\ln a> x\ln b$ if $x>0$, and hence as the function $e^x$ is increasing, $e^{x\ln a}>e^{x\ln b}$, i.e. $a^x>b^x$. This holds for all real $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b>0, a^x<$ or $>b^x$ iff $\left(\frac ab\right)^x<$ or $>1$

Now, if $a>b,$

$\left(\frac ab\right)^x>1$  if $x>0$ and $\left(\frac ab\right)^x<1$ if $x<0$